# Hover для кнопки копирования для Prism js

Tags: css, hover, prism

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на окно с кодом появлялась кнопка копирования? Окно с кодом `.codes`.

Код копирования выглядит так:

```
pre[class*="language-"] .copy {
    content: "copy";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.codes:hover pre[class*="language-"] .copy { display: block; }
```

перед css кодом основным ставим дисплей блок.

```
pre[class*="language-"] .copy { 
display: none;
content: "copy";
position: absolute;
bottom: 4px;
right: 6px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 200ms ease; }
```

скрываем блок.

Блок будет появляться только при наведении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда, значок копирования до наведения курсора торчит слева над кодом, а при наведении он появляется в нужном месте. Может,  дать ссылку на пример (без hover)?

Comment: @Plutooo пример кода скопируйте сюда. он ведь не полный тут. Мне гадать приходится ради ответа для вас.

Comment: @Plutooo отредактировал ответ. Настолько, насколько понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: Владимир, большое спасибо за ответ!